# How to run .swf file in any pc? without any movie player

Tags: actionscript, flash

I hv a done a project in FLASH for a client. I hv used ActionScript 3 to hide mouse and used full screen code in FRAME 1 in flash file. But the client is saying he is not getting the full screen and Mouse hide after opening the .SWF file.  But It is running well in my PC. My code is given below.

(1) Pls any one provide some guide in this situation.
 (2) How the client can open the .swf file in his pc.
    In some PC it does not open (unknown file format)?
    Any plugin is required to easily run .SWF file?

```
/* Used in Action on first frame */
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
    Mouse.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

For ActionScript, you can make your swf on fullscreen mode using [`fscommand()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/package.html#fscommand%28%29) :

```
fscommand('fullscreen', 'true');
fscommand('allowscale', 'false');
Mouse.hide()
```

And then, you can export your swf as a projector ( an .exe file, including the swf and [Flash Player](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Player), which your final user can open in any windows machine ) which will be opened in fullscreen mode automatically.

From Flash IDE, you can make a projector by going to menu **File** > **Publish Settings ...** > Publish - **Other Formats** > **Win Projector** and then type the name of your exe file as **Output file** and press the **publish** button to save your exe in same dir as your swf.

Then you have just to distribute the projector to your final users.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of **Adobe Flash Professional CC**, the Create Prejector/ Export as Projector can be done by installing **"Export as Projector" Add-on** (it is free)